# How to get rid of accept: Already open exception in boost::asio server

Tags: boost, boost-asio

This server, which is running in a separate thread, seemingly functions well except for the frequently thrown exception "accept: Already open exception". This exception is thrown on acceptor.accept(...) call, on checking whether the socket is already open. If I call the accepter.accept(...) iff socket is not open (commented line), the behaviour becomes unpredictable. The run method gets data from a synchronized mQueue, which is being filled on another thread at about 30 times per second.

What am I doing wrong?

```
class Server{
    public:

Server(unsigned short port, ConcurrentQueue<uint8_t*>*queueToServer, unsigned int width, unsigned int height):mSocket(mIOService),mAcceptor(mIOService,ip::tcp::endpoint(ip::tcp::v4(), port)),mQueue(queueToServer), dSize(width*height*3){}
void run(){

    unsigned char* data;
    boost::system::error_code ignored_error;
    while(true){
        if (mQueue->try_pop(data)){
            const mutable_buffer image_buffer(data, dSize);
            //if (!mSocket.is_open())
            mAcceptor.accept(mSocket);
            boost::asio::write(mSocket, buffer(image_buffer), transfer_all(), ignored_error);
        }
    }
}
private:
    io_service mIOService;
    ip::tcp::socket mSocket;
    ip::tcp::acceptor mAcceptor;
    ConcurrentQueue<uint8_t*>* mQueue;
    std::size_t dSize;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

In asio terms, a socket is "open" if it has a valid socket handle (descriptor). When you accepting an incoming connection, you should pass to the acceptor a "fresh", unopen socket.
So, the problem is in the logic of your code: you should first accept a new connection from your client, and then you can use the accepted socket to send/receive any data you want.

Comment: R: Right, I fixed this by calling mSocket.close() after the write call. Thanks a lot.